# Case-insensitive comparison in SELECT condition

Tags: abap, opensql

In ABAP SQL can I ignore the case when comparing fields in the `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE field1 = variable1.
```

How can I compare `field1` to `variable1` ignoring different case?

Comment: Thank you for your guys' help. I use native sql as my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the table you are selecting from, you may be lucky in that SAP is storing the same value in a related matchcode field, in which the value would always be upper case.

Otherwise, you may find something in the documentation of the underlying DB that allows such a search, in which case you may issue a native SELECT.

For example, if your SAP system uses Oracle as the underlying DB, you can refer to this article: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/2005_5_20_great_technique_case_sensitive_text_searching.htm

Comment: An example of the first paragraph would be tables `EQUI` and `EQKT`. The field  `EQKTU`. stores the upper case description.

Answer (score 6):

Open SQL can do this with the function [`UPPER`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/de-DE/abensql_function_upper_abexa.htm) starting ABAP [7.51](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abennews-751-open_sql.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_4@4@).

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE UPPER( field1 ) = @variable1
INTO TABLE @DATA(internal_table).
```

Comment: happy to know. I have been waiting this feature for quite a few years.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Open SQL does not support case insensitive conditions.

You can either do what mydoghasworms suggested or you filter your results using regex after data selection.

Answer (score 1):

*OpenSQL* can't do this - like the others mentioned alreay in earlier statements.

But there is one alternative: **Native SQL**, the "upper" function, means:

```
translate compare_value to upper case.

exec sql performing addX.
  select * FROM  INTO :workarea
   where upper("choose_column") eq :compare_value
endexec.

form addX.
  append workarea to itab.
endform.
```